# If $\forall a>0$ the function $f$ is differentiable on $]a,\infty[$ then is differentiable on $]0,\infty[$

Tags: real-analysis

I have this simple question:

Let $f:\mathbb{R}_+\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a function such that  $\forall a>0$, $f$ is differentiable  on $]a,\infty[$ how to prove that it is differentiable on $]0,+\infty[$?

Thank you for any answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $ x>0$.

if we take $a=\frac x2$, then

$$0<a<x$$
but $f$ is differentiable at $]a,+\infty[$, thus $ f$ is differentiable at $ x$ since $ x\in ]a +\infty[$.

$ f$ is differentiable at any point $ x>0 $, is differentiable at $ ]0,+\infty[$.

Answer (score 1):

Use the set equation
$$]0,+\infty[ = \bigcup_{a > 0}\, ]a,+\infty[
$$
Differentiability of $f$ on $]0,+\infty[$ simply means that for each $x \in \, ]-,+\infty[$, $f$ is differentiable at $x$; using $a=x/2 > 0$, this is implied by the fact that $x \in \, ]a,+\infty[$ and that $f$ is differentiable on $]a,+\infty[$.

Answer (score 0):

A bit more of the same :

Let $x_0 \in (0,\infty)$;

There is a $n_0 \in \mathbb{Z^+}$ s.t. $1/n_0 <x_0$.

Set $a:=1/n_0$;

$f$ is differentiable on $(a,\infty);$

$f$ is differentiable at $x_0;$

$f$ is differentiable on $(0,\infty)$.